# Django display limited images in grid row

Tags: python, django, grid

As mentioned in the title. **Is it possible to display a specific number of photos in a particular grid-container?** For example, a maximum of 3 columns with a card in the row using a loop?
I was able to achieve the effect of displaying all the photos from the defined model,***but I don't know how to set the limit***.

Below I present fragments of the code responsible for displaying the created model

**forms.py**

```
class ProductsForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ('name', 'description', 'image', 'file_type')
```

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
file_type = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=[('image', 'image'), ('thumbnail', 'thumbnail')], default='')

image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products', default='')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
def gallery(request):
image = Product.objects.filter(file_type='image')
thumbnail = Product.objects.filter(file_type='thumbnail')
return render(request, 'products/fruits.html', {'img': image, 'thumb': thumbnail})
```

**fruits.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load thumbnail %}
{% block body_block %}

<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="card-deck">


        {% for i in thumb %}
            {% thumbnail i.image "150x150" crop="center" as im %}

                <!-- Card -->
                <div class="card mb-4">

                    <!--Card image-->
                    <div class="view overlay">

                        <img src="{{ im.url }}"
                             alt="Card image cap">
                        <a href="#!">
                            <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <!--Card content-->
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <!--Title-->
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <!--Text-->
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                            the
                            bulk
                            of
                            the
                            card's
                            content.</p>
                        <!-- Provides extra visual weight and identifies the primary action in a set of buttons -->
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light-blue btn-md">Read more</button>

                    </div>

                </div>

            {% endthumbnail %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: you want a stop the loop exactly at three photos?

Comment: not exactly, after setting the first 3, I would like the following to be created in the next row.

Comment: basically you need to set 3 by row, and so one

Comment: as you can see in the code I create a new card object for each photo and all of them form in one row. Maybe you could show me in example how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build-in Django filter `divisibleby` may work, inside your loop, you check whether the iteration is divisible by (in your case) `3`, then you break the row to jump to another one:

```
{% for i in thumb %}
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
         ----------
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think it is working when I am using:

`{% block body_block %}

    {% for thumbnail in thumb %}
        {% thumbnail thumbnail.image "150x150" crop='center' as img %}
            {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:2 %}
                <div class="row"></div>
            {% endif %}
            <img src="{{ img.url }}">
            {#            <img src="{{ img.url }}">#}
        {% endthumbnail %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}`

without any bootstrap code.. but by adding the code which I placed in the main thread, everything goes apart.. Any ideas ?

Comment: why starting from zero `forloop.counter0`? break line will be after [0,2,4,6,8....]

Comment: it does not achieve the intended goal after all.. I am not sure if we understand each other well. I need all images from the database to be displayed 3 times per row. So in the case of 15 photos 5 rows of 3 photos (3 columns) should be displayed one next to the other in the generated card

Comment: *With bootstrap* it's easy to do, *without it* what you need to do is inside the loop you add the image followed a `if else statement` whether the iteration is divisible by 3 like my above answer, you add a **CSS trick** or a **block HTML tag** to create a new row...

Comment: U mentioned that with bootstrap it's easy. So why if I am using it like in main topic above, it doesn't work ? Do you see any mistakes I made ? or maybe you have any example ?

Comment: `{% for loop %} <div class="col-md-4">  img </div> {% endfor %}` the grid of boostrap is a grid of 12 columns, with 3 `4-columns`, bootstrap will break the row after 3 img

Comment: You had completely right. The problem was with "Material Design for Bootstrap 4" which I had used. I am not sure what generate the problem, but if I found it, I will definitely post the answer here ! Thanks you soo much

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what you want to do by creating a list of lists of images in the view, then send this list to the HTML template and display it with two loops. The advantage of this approach is that you can control the number of columns by changing one variable. Each element of the main list contains X number of columns.

The idea is  to send a list like the one represented below (more or less)

photos_list = [[photo1, photo2, ... photoN], [photo1, photo2, ... photoN]]

the view code is:

```
def index(request):
    photos = Photo.objects.all()
    counter = -1
    columns_qty = 5 # << Just change this number for the columns you want
    photos_row = []
    photos_list = []
    for photo in photos:
        counter += 1
        if counter < columns_qty:
            photos_row.append(photo)
        else:
            photos_list.append(photos_row)
            photos_row = []
            counter = -1
    context = {'photos_list': photos_list}
    return render(request, 'photos/index.html', context)
```

the model code is:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length= 250)
    original_path = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    saved_path = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    file_size = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    file_created = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    file_last_modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    loaded_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    def __str__(self):
        return self.file_name
```

and the html template code is:

```
{% extends 'photos/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<table>
    {% for photo_row in photos_list %}
    <tr>
        {% for photo_col in photo_row %}
            <td><img src="{% static photo_col.file_name %}" width="300px"
             height="auto"></td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

{% endblock %}
```

I hope this helps!